# How do you Right align a paragraph?

Tags: google-docs

I try to align a single paragraph to the right (Right align), but it Right aligns the whole chapter no matter how I make the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the cursor in the paragraph. It's not necessary to select the whole thing. In fact, you shouldn't "select" anything.

Use the right-align tool. Either the right-align button the menu bar, the menu (`Format > Align > Right`), or the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

See my before and after screen shots below.

[image: before]

[image: after - second paragraph is right-aligned]

Comment: I just found out the text paragraphs were somehow joined together so google docs thought the chapter was one paragraph. I fixed it by making newlines after a paragraph.

Comment: Did you happen to copy and paste the original text into the doc or something?  I have seen it get confused about what a paragraph is if you didn't do your original composition, in Google Docs.